# Data binding MaterialTextView ClassCastException when using custom font on project

Tags: android

I am using Data Binding, MVVM architecture in my project.

It worked just fine before, but suddenly app crashes when the activity tries to launch this layout. It says **com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to** com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView** when I didn't use MaterialTextView at all in any place of the project.

The things I checked

- It is not about SpinKitViewLibrary when I moved line app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.isLoading}" this to some button. it says MaterialTextView can't be cast to button as well.
- I'm using the same visibleGone BindingAdapter more than 10 fragments in this project. It works just fine.
- When I deleted  <variable
  name="viewModel" // This part is problem 1
  type="com.junga.clabvoca.viewmodel.login.LoginViewModel" /> the layout didn't crash

**The layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel" // This part is problem 1
        type="com.junga.clabvoca.viewmodel.login.LoginViewModel" />

  </data>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_login_main_1">

   ...

    <com.junga.clabvoca.view.customview.CustomBasicButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_naver_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/naver_green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_kakao_login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_right"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_left"
        app:text="네이버로 로그인"
        app:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp" />

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
        android:id="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.isLoading}" **// This part is problem 2**
        app:SpinKit_Color="?android:colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/v_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@integer/guideline_small_v_left" />


   

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**The Activity file**

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding


lateinit var  mOAuthLoginModule : OAuthLogin
lateinit var viewModel : LoginViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_login) // Error occurs here 

    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

**Binding Adapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:visibleGone")
fun showHide(view: View, show: Boolean) {
    Logger.log("app visible gone : $show")
    try{
    view.setVisibility(if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
    }catch (e : Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
        Logger.error(e.stackTrace.toString())
    }
}
```

**Error Stack trace**

2021-04-14 19:33:11.493 7794-7794/com.junga.clabvoca W/System.err: **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to** com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
2021-04-14 19:33:11.493 7794-7794/com.junga.clabvoca W/System.err:     at com.junga.clabvoca.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl.(ActivityLoginBindingImpl.java:38)
2021-04-14 19:33:11.493 7794-7794/com.junga.clabvoca W/System.err:     at com.junga.clabvoca.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl.(ActivityLoginBindingImpl.java:35)
2021-04-14 19:33:11.493 7794-7794/com.junga.clabvoca W/System.err:     at com.junga.clabvoca.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:188)
2021-04-14 19:33:11.493 7794-7794/com.junga.clabvoca W/System.err:     at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:74)

**Login ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val mRepo = LogInRepository()
    val postLoginResponse = mRepo.postLoginResponse

    val isLoading = MutableLiveData(false)
    val isWhat = MutableLiveData(false)

     fun isLoading(flag : Boolean) {
        isLoading.value = flag
    }

    fun getPostLoginResponse() : LiveData<Resource<PostLoginResponse>> = postLoginResponse
    fun postLogin(postData : PostLogin){
        mRepo.postLogin(postData)
    }

    val getUserResponse = mRepo.getUserResopnse
    fun getGetUserResponse(): LiveData<Resource<GetUserResponse>> = getUserResponse
    fun getUser(){
        mRepo.getUser()
    }


}
```

could this caused by the way I implemented viewModel and data binding in the activity? I am so stucked :(

**21.04.14 Update**

I solved this issue somehow and I still don't know why it didn't work.
So I had a binding adapter that converts font depending on the theme user chosen. The bindin adapter looked like this

```
@BindingAdapter("app:setFont")
fun setTextStyle(view: TextView, type : String){
        try {
            Logger.log("set text style")

            if(AppPreferences.font == 0){
                when(type){

                    "regular" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.REGULAR_1.fontRes)
                    }

                    "medium" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.MEDIUM_1.fontRes)
                    }

                    "bold" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.BOLD_1.fontRes)
                    }
                }
            }else if(AppPreferences.font == 1){
                when(type){

                    "regular", "medium" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.MEDIUM_2.fontRes)
                    }

                    "bold" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.BOLD_2.fontRes)
                    }
                }
            }else {
                when(type){
                    "regular", "medium" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.MEDIUM_3.fontRes)
                    }

                    "bold" -> {
                        view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, FontTypes.BOLD_3.fontRes)
                    }
                }
            }


        }catch (e :Exception){

        }
}
```

And the error happens, when I didn't set that binding adapter value on the textview where I set the style attribute.

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo_text"
            style="@style/Header2.Bold.White"
            app:setFont="@{@string/bold}" // without line this occur error
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/logo_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logo_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

but without style attribute, It is okay not to use app:setFont attribute.

***So the thing was I needed to set setFont whenever I use style attr on textview. This is so weird behavior and I want to know why.***

Answer (score 1):

Change function to static.

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("app:setFont")
    fun setTextStyle(view: TextView, type : String) {
        ...
    }
}
```